# Moment.js "Invalid date" for specific datetime format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using `moment.js` code for datetime as below

```
var someday = moment("09/08/2022 05:46:00 PM", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS A", "en-US", true);
someday.isValid(); // This is returning 'false'
```

Above code returns `false` and I end up with `"Invalid date"`.
it seems like moment doesn't support this format because below code works properly.

```
var someday = moment("09/08/2022", "MM/DD/YYYY", "en-US", true);
```

If that is the case that moment doesn't support format `"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS A"` , what should I do to achieve that ?

Why I need this format ? - I am getting this date format from API and I need to use it as it is coming from API.

Comment: Parsing format tokens are [case-sensitive](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Try [`MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A`](https://jsfiddle.net/zu5vc7do/)?

Comment: Yes it worked. Found one code in our codebase which was converting fieldFormat to upper case. Thank you so much for the quick reply. You can add this as an answer.

Comment: I'm not so sure the comment deserves to be an answer since it was only a typo.